# Set listener for a child of a child of recyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a RecyclerView which there are three buttons in its model,
how can I set a listener for each button? I can access RecyclerView's child and set a listener for it but I want to set a listener for a child of a child of RecyclerView. Consider that I'm using Kotlin.

I used this code which let you access the child of recyclerView, but not the child of the child of RecyclerView:

```
fun RecyclerView.addOnItemClickListener(onClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(object: RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
        override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
            view.setOnClickListener(null)
        }
        override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val holder = getChildViewHolder(view)
                onClickListener.onItemClicked(holder.adapterPosition, view)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Add your implementation what have you tried so far

Comment: Always add some implementation of your work with question. :)

Comment: You can add button click in your adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to set `OnClickListener` on each `Button` of `RecyclerView` item. Check below as an example

```
class YourAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener {

    //Other code
    ....

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourAdapter.YourViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.button1.setOnClickListener(this)
        holder.button2.setOnClickListener(this)
        holder.button3.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id) {
            R.id.button1 -> {
                //Do your operation
            }

            R.id.button2 -> {
                //Do your operation
            }

            R.id.button3 -> {
                //Do your operation
            }
        }
    }

    class YourViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        lateinit var button1: Button
        lateinit var button2: Button
        lateinit var button3: Button
    }
}
```